# SQL Server connection error: SSL Provider, error: 0 - One or more of the parameters passed to the function was invalid

Tags: sql-server, ssl, database-connection, connection-string

We just implemented a new database server. The operating system (OS) is Windows Server 2022 Standard, and the database version is SQL Server 2022 Standard (SS2022).

When requesting a website that points to the this new database instance, the website throws the following error:

> SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established
> with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
> (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - One or more of the parameters
> passed to the function was invalid.)

The connection string works fine when pointing to the former database that we're attempting to replace, hosted on an OS2008R2 server. The connection string looks like this . . . (Note that I changed the values for security, but these are the key/value pairs included):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=website;Password=********;Max Pool Size=32767" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

References to the first part of this error message (". . . error occurred during the login process.") frequently advise adding one or both of the following to the connection string: Encrypt=False and/or TrustServerCertificate=True. Unfortunately, no combination of these key/value pairs solves the problem.

It appears that the key text from this error may be: "provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - One or more of the parameters passed to the function was invalid."

This precise error appears to be rare because I can find very little out there, and what is out there generally references registry settings for TLS protocols and cipher suites, which I have very little understanding of. Our managed services provider has confirmed that both the web server and the database server have both TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 enabled. With that, we are stumped.

Any help troubleshooting this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I subsequently attempted to connect to the SS2022 database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS, version 2008 R2). This instance of SSMS is installed on the the same OS2008R2 web server as the above-mentioned website. SSMS threw the following similar error (I hid the IP in the error message below):

> Cannot connect to XX.XX.XX.XXX. A connection was successfully
> established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - One or more
> of the parameters passed to the function was invalid.) (Microsoft SQL
> Server)

Note that this error is slightly different than the website error in that it specifically references the "pre-login handshake."

Comment: Which version of .Net and Windows is the client application (the web server) running? Exact build numbers please. If you can, get a Wireshark trace on the Client Hello and Server Hello of the connection, and see if there is a cipher mismatch.

Comment: Do you see any correlated messages in the SQL Server instance's Error Log? e.g.: if it were a credentials/login error you'd see Error 18456 messages and you could compare their State numbers against those at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16) to determine the cause. But, given System.Data.SqlClient hasn't see any real development since 2019, I would expect there are other issues involved such as TDS 8.0 (new to SQL Server 2022) and/or TLS 1.3 usage.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback! (Please note the update that I just added to the question above.) The site is running .NET version 4.7.2, and the web server OS build is 6.1.7601. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the SQL Server error log. I did ask our database administrator to investigate, and I'm sure that he must have checked this log. He kicked the case back to me and suggested that our managed service provider check the server protocols and ciphers. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: OK you need to install the latest updates for Windows Server 2008R2, in particular the ones mentioned on this page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 and also follow all the instructions there to enable TLS 1.2 in the registry. You can also use the free IIS Crypto tool to do this second step. I **strongly** recommend you upgrade from 2008 as it is now heavily out of date and unsupported, and has serious vulnerabilities

Comment: Update management studio. I suspect 2008 R2 is too old and using incorrect or obsoleted protocols/ciphers.

Comment: In response to Charlieface, I confirmed that KB3140245 was previously installed and that TLS1.2 was previously enabled. (I agree that we need to upgrade from all OS2008 servers. In fact, we're in the process of migrating our databases to newer servers now. Hence, this issue.) Joel, we have 2008 R2 versions of Management Studio installed on another OS2008R2 server (dev version) and are able to successfully connect to the new database server from there. I'm now wondering if we need to disable some older ciphers rather than enable some newer ones? Thank you both! I'm open to your responses/ideas.

Comment: Possibly there is a mismatch in what ciphers are available. You might need to use IIS Crypto to enable some older ciphers on the newer boxes.

Comment: "enable some older ciphers on newer boxes". This could work, **but please don't do that**. Those ciphers are disabled for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

We learned that there was no overlap between the TLS 1.2 ciphers enabled on the web server and the TLS 1.2 ciphers enabled on the database server. This issue was resolved when our managed services provider enabled just one cipher on the web server that was already enabled on the database server.

Enabling that cipher was the resolution for this problem, but I'm still confused by Microsoft's choice of words for the inner exception on this error message:

```
SSL Provider, error: 0 - One or more of the parameters passed to the function was invalid.
```

In my case, a lot of time would have been saved if that language was clearer.

Incidentally, all the feedback in the comments above are much appreciated!